# How to use create function instead of perform_create in ListCreateApiView in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, view, django-generic-views

**I am trying to create a booking api for a website**.

For this, I used perform_create function in `ListCreateApiView`. But, it was someone else who helped me and told me to use `perform_create` function.

But, I was thinking, it should be possible using `create` function and is a right approach rather than `perform_create` function.

Also, **I don't really know the difference between these two functions and don't really know when to use which**

**Here is my code:**

```
    class BookingCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
        permission_classes= [IsAuthenticated]
        queryset = Booking.objects.all()
        serializer_class = BookingSerializer
    
        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            # user = self.request.user
            package = get_object_or_404(Package, pk= self.kwargs['pk'])
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user,package=package)
```

**Here is my serializer:**

```
    class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        # blog = serializers.StringRelatedField()
        class Meta:
            model = Booking
            fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'bookedfor']
```

**Here is my model:**

```
    class Booking(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='package')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        email = models.EmailField()
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        bookedfor = models.DateField()
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('created_at',)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you looking in source code:
ListCreateApiView call

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

then inside `create` call

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

That mean `perform_create` called after `serializer` validated.

And for what you want, you can override different method.

In my opinion:

- If you want custom `Response` return from api, you override `create`
- If you want doing anything special after `serializer` validated, but before `object` created in database, you override `perform_create`. Like your example, it want checking `Package` exists and save `request.user` in field `user`

Comment: What about after item is created?

Comment: you must use signal post save. Its trigger after one item saved. Both new item created and old item called save